# How do you deal with a large number of EventListeners?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I am currently working on a comment feature. There can be many comments > 100. Each comment has several functions (Delete, Edit, Flag) that the user can click on.
If I assume there are 100 comments with three 3 functions. There are 300 event listeners that I have initialised.

**Problem** Now I wonder if this has a negative impact on the performance of the browser? I suppose so.

**Question** Is there a more performance approach that can be used? A pattern that was designed for exactly such cases?

Comment: Event Delegation

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+event+delegation+many+eventlisteners+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation

Comment: Wrap each comment in a container. Add the ID of the comment to that container as a data-attribute. Wrap all comments in one container and use delegation from that to intercept clicks. Use `const parent = e.target.closest('div.comment') as parent and get the id from there. You can the do parent.remove() if the e.target is delete and parent.dataset.commentid to get the id of the comment if needed

Comment: @mplungjan Your comment (event delegation) was helpful and it make sense. I will try out. Thank you

Comment: For example https://stackoverflow.com/a/33015903/295783 and do not forget to use the tweak added to it

Comment: @mplungjan What do you mean with tweak?

Comment: @mplungjan Would you mean that I assign each comment as a container to an event or the whole comment list? In the first approach I would have 100 EventListeners and in the second approach only one. Which would be super super :-) I would say that the second approach would work but I don't know the side effects that could occur.

Comment: Event Delegation is the way to go indeed. But instead of `id's` I prefer using data-attributes. Like `<button data-function="Delete" data-message="347">..</button>`. Then point the eventhandler to the right function trough `dataset.function` and the right messsage trough `dataset.message`

Comment: @Michel That sound very! good :-) I will try. Can you take a look to my comment above and give me your opinion, please? `Would you mean that I assign each comment as a container to an event or the whole comment list? In the first approach I would have 100 EventListeners and in the second approach only one. Which would be super super :-) I would say that the second approach would work but I don't know the side effects that could occur.`

Comment: Only *one* eventlistener attached to the entire document. And from there just let the data-attributes tell the eventlistener what to do, and on what message. The fun part is if you have a menu or something else, you can add those to the same eventlistener: `<div data-function="menu" data-menuoption="7">`

Comment: @Michel With this approch i need for all click event on my side only one listener. And the magic what is to do make the eventHandler. Im flashed :-)

Comment: Here is a complete example https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/8p4r5cwx/

Comment: @mplungjan Great thanks to you for your time and afforts! It is a good example. I am testing it now and will apply it to my project. I suspect that I will have a problem with event bubbling later on, because my buttons still contain two spans where I already work with currentTarget. Can the two approaches be combined? I will ask a new question when I encounter the problem and ping you and Michel...

Comment: `const tgtButtonWhenSpansInsideButton = e.target.closest("button")` would handle any click on a `<button><span>Click</span> <span>Me</span> Now</button>`

Comment: @mplungjan As I had already suspected, I will run into exactly the same problem if the button contains two more elements. Thanks for your hint but i had problems with closest. I open a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75172827/event-delegation-does-not-work-if-the-bound-target-is-nested .  Maybe you did it :-)

Comment: @Michel can you take a look to my related question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75172827/event-delegation-does-not-work-if-the-bound-target-is-nested

Comment: @Michel is my namesake...

Comment: @mplungjan :-) the official: Merci Michel and Michel!