# Event delegation does not work if the bound target is nested

Tags: javascript, html, css

For a comment list I use the event **delegation pattern** after a recommendation from Stackoverflow colleagues (*mplungjan, Michel*). It works well and I am very enthusiastic about this pattern. But as I already suspected, there will be problems if the bound element (button) contains two child elements (`span, span`).

Since I want to get the CommentID from the target in the parent element of the child element, it only works in the cases when you click exactly between the spans inside the button. Actually a case for currentTarget but that doesn't work in this case because the tapped element is the whole comment list.

**Question:** What do I have to do to fix it?

```js
const commentList = document.querySelector('.comment-list');

commentList.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
  console.log('1. clicked');
  const getObjectId = () => {
    return ev.target.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute('data-comment-id');
  }
  
  if (! getObjectId()) return false;

  if (ev.target.classList.contains('delete')) {
    console.log('2. Delete action');
    console.log('3. for relatedID', getObjectId());
  }
  
  if (ev.target.classList.contains('edit')) {
    console.log('2. Edit action');
    console.log('3. for relatedID', getObjectId());
  }  
  
  if (ev.target.classList.contains('flag')) {
    console.log('2. Flag action');
    console.log('3. for relatedID', getObjectId());
  }    
  
});
```

```css
.controller {
  display: flex;
  gap:20px;
}
.comment {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: gray;
}

.controller button > span {
  background: orange;
}

.controller button span:first-child {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="comment-list">
  <div class="comment">
    <div class="content">lorem 1. Dont work! Nested button.</div>
    <div class="controller" data-comment-id="1">
      <div class="delete">
        <button class="delete"><span>delete</span><span>ICON</span></button>        
      </div>
      <div class="edit">
        <button class="edit"><span>edit</span><span>ICON</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="flag">
        <button class="flag"><span>flag</span><span>ICON</span></button>          
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="comment">
    <div class="content">lorem 2. Work! </div>
    <div class="controller" data-comment-id="2">
      <div class="delete"><button class="delete">delete</button></div>
      <div class="edit"><button class="edit">edit</button></div>
      <div class="flag"><button class="flag">flag</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="comment">
    <div class="content">lorem 3. Work! </div>
    <div class="controller" data-comment-id="3">
      <div class="delete"><button class="delete">delete</button></div>
      <div class="edit"><button class="edit">edit</button></div>
      <div class="flag"><button class="flag">flag</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>  
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on my last comment in [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75171007/295783)

`const tgtButtonWhenSpansInsideButton = e.target.closest("button")`

1. Cache the objects
2. the closest method will get the button itself even if no children
3. Make sure you get the class from the containing element of what you want to call a button

```js
const commentList = document.querySelector('.comment-list');
const getObjectId = (tgt) => tgt.closest('.controller').dataset.commentId;

commentList.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
  const tgt = ev.target.closest("button")
  const objectId = getObjectId(tgt);
  if (!objectId) return;
  console.log(objectId,"clicked")
  if (tgt.classList.contains('delete')) {
    console.log('2. Delete action');
    console.log('3. for relatedID', objectId);
  }

  if (tgt.classList.contains('edit')) {
    console.log('2. Edit action');
    console.log('3. for relatedID', objectId);
  }

  if (tgt.classList.contains('flag')) {
    console.log('2. Flag action');
    console.log('3. for relatedID', objectId);
  }

});
```

```css
.controller {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}

.comment {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: gray;
}

.controller button>span {
  background: orange;
}

.controller button span:first-child {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="comment-list">
  <div class="comment">
    <div class="content">lorem 1. Dont work! Nested button.</div>
    <div class="controller" data-comment-id="1">
      <div class="delete">
        <button class="delete"><span>delete</span><span>ICON</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="edit">
        <button class="edit"><span>edit</span><span>ICON</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="flag">
        <button class="flag"><span>flag</span><span>ICON</span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="comment">
    <div class="content">lorem 2. Work! </div>
    <div class="controller" data-comment-id="2">
      <div class="delete"><button class="delete">delete</button></div>
      <div class="edit"><button class="edit">edit</button></div>
      <div class="flag"><button class="flag">flag</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="comment">
    <div class="content">lorem 3. Work! </div>
    <div class="controller" data-comment-id="3">
      <div class="delete"><button class="delete">delete</button></div>
      <div class="edit"><button class="edit">edit</button></div>
      <div class="flag"><button class="flag">flag</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for your answer. I will accept in view minutes. Have a nice day. It is really nice to exchange ideas with good colleagues! top!

Comment: YW. Event delegation is one of my hobbyhorses.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're using `.parentNode.parentNode` to get to the element with `data-comment-id`, but the number of parents changes when the target is nested inside additional `<span>` elements.

Don't hard-code the nesting levels, use `.closest()` to find the containing controller node.

```
  const getObjectId = () => {
    return ev.target.closest('.controller').getAttribute('data-comment-id');
  }
```

Comment: Actually this is a better option than mine, but it only solves one of the issues - OP also needs to update the `ev.target.classList`, because they are identifying the operation based on the class of the topmost element that was clicked

Comment: Thank you Barmar! Im very happy for the help!

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would "traverse" the DOM up if it wasn't a button that was clicked, something like this

```js
const commentList = document.querySelector('.comment-list');

commentList.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
  console.log('1. clicked', ev.target.tagName);

  let target = ev.target
  if (target.tagName === "SPAN") {
    target = target.parentElement
  }

  const commentId = target.parentElement.parentElement.getAttribute('data-comment-id');
  
  if (!commentId) return false;

  if (target.classList.contains('delete')) {
    console.log('2. Delete action');
    console.log('3. for relatedID', commentId);
  }
  
  if (target.classList.contains('edit')) {
    console.log('2. Edit action');
    console.log('3. for relatedID', commentId);
  }  
  
  if (target.classList.contains('flag')) {
    console.log('2. Flag action');
    console.log('3. for relatedID', commentId);
  }    
  
});
```

```css
.controller {
  display: flex;
  gap:20px;
}
.comment {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: gray;
}

.controller button > span {
  background: orange;
}

.controller button span:first-child {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="comment-list">
  <div class="comment">
    <div class="content">lorem 1. Dont work! Nested button.</div>
    <div class="controller" data-comment-id="1">
      <div class="delete">
        <button class="delete"><span>delete</span><span>ICON</span></button>        
      </div>
      <div class="edit">
        <button class="edit"><span>edit</span><span>ICON</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="flag">
        <button class="flag"><span>flag</span><span>ICON</span></button>          
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="comment">
    <div class="content">lorem 2. Work! </div>
    <div class="controller" data-comment-id="2">
      <div class="delete"><button class="delete">delete</button></div>
      <div class="edit"><button class="edit">edit</button></div>
      <div class="flag"><button class="flag">flag</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="comment">
    <div class="content">lorem 3. Work! </div>
    <div class="controller" data-comment-id="3">
      <div class="delete"><button class="delete">delete</button></div>
      <div class="edit"><button class="edit">edit</button></div>
      <div class="flag"><button class="flag">flag</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>  
  
</div>
```

Comment: Oh and also include .closest() like Barmar suggested

Comment: Thanks Joel! Three quick and good answers in a very short time. Thank you very much!